# Getting Browser not supported for Report Viewer - Visual studio 2019

Tags: reportviewer

I am creating webforms for Report Viewer of my SSRS, with Visual studio 2019 and .net framework 4.8 version. In default.aspx I have given  meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" in head section of page still I am getting browser not supported though I am using edge to browse it

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9hLX.png)

Expecting solution for this